# psycopg2 Installation Problems

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

When I start my Django server, I get the following error:

```
Failed to get real commands on module "mysite": python process died with code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py", line 25, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
```

When I checked the `psycopg2` directory after you installed the library, `__init__.py` contains `from psycopg2._psycopg import ...`. But there is no `_psycopg.dll` file in the `psycopg2` directory. Possible bug?

Part of my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "database1",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "123456",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432"
    }
}
```

**Using:**

Windows 10

PyCharm

Anaconda

Python 3.8.3

psycopg2 2.8.4

Django 3.0.3

PostgreSQL

Comment: how did you install psycopg2

Comment: `conda activate mysite`, 

`conda install django`, 

`conda install psycopg2`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it to work.

I had to switch out of the Anaconda environment to a Virtualenv environment and install with Pip, maintaining the same set-up.

So the problem was either with how Anaconda handled **psycopg2** or there was a problem with the library itself because the latest version of **psycopg2** on Anaconda was older by 0.0.x

A small version difference, but it might've been missing a hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue
I have added path to `bin` folder of `postgres` to `PATH`.
It helped.